# How to calculate interval time when same button clicked 3 times and 4 times in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

There is one button in JavaScript of jQuery. The first time I press the button, after some seconds again I press the same button. I got the code for calculating interval between two clicks of the same button from Stack Overflow. How can I calculate interval between first click and third click of the same button, and first click and fourth click of the same button. Please help.

Code to calculate interval time between first and second click:

```
var startTime;
$("#bu").on('click', function() {
    if(startTime) {
        alert( "Time difference: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) );
        startTime = undefined;
    } else {
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var clickTimes = [];
$("#bu").on('click', function() {
  var clickTime = new Date().getTime();

  for (var i = 0; i < clickTimes.length; i++) {
    var difference = clickTime - clickTimes[i];

    alert("Time since click " + (i + 1) + ": " + difference);
  }

  clickTimes.push(clickTime);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="bu" value="Click me"/>
```

By storing all the times the button was clicked in an array, you can calculate the difference between any two clicks at any point. So for the third and the fourth click, respectively, it would be:

```
var timeBetweenFirstAndThirdClick = clickTimes[2] - clickTimes[0];
var timeBetweenFirstAndFourthClick = clickTimes[3] - clickTimes[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push time in array when button is clicked and using that array you can find difference between any clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you meant!

```
var startTime;
var count1 =1;
$("#bu").on('click', function() {

    if(startTime) {

        alert( "difference start and "+ count1 +"click: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) );
        count1++;
    } else {
        startTime = new Date().getTime();

    }
});
```